# Fix a control's id inside a Listview

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a textbox with a required field validator inside a listview. The problem right now is the page has a number of dynamically generated steps that when is loaded, they go through a validator basically done by using the jQuery Page.Validate() to see if there are any fields that were missing required values. I am getting a javascript error on this required field validator that is on this listview where its complaining about the id having dashes. See below.

[image]

Is there a way to clean this id up so it gets rid of the dashes as we all know, jQuery doesn't like the dashes in the variable name. How would I go about cleaning this up? I am getting the console error below.

[image]

[image]

Let me know if additional details are required. Thanks!

Comment: please share your code so we can see what you are dealing with

Comment: I was trying to see what I could include as this is a 10 year old app and I was brought into this in to make some tweaks. Let me go through the scripts thats doing the page validation and maybe include some of that. Hope that would help in getting this started and can add more if required. I apologize for not providing enough details to start with.